# How to get value from a multi-array?

Tags: php

I want to get a specific value of a variable from multi array, if the condition matches.

*When I print my array:*

```
print_r($myarray);
```

*gives array like this:*

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
   (
     [id] => 21 //check for this value
     [customer_id] => 12456 //get this value 
     [date] => 12-06-2017         
   )
  [1] => Array
   (
     [id] => 15
     [customer_id] => 12541 
     [date] => 12-06-2017
   )
  [2] => Array
   (
     [id] => 12
     [customer_id] => 25415
     [date] => 12-06-2017
   )
)
```

I am trying to get **customer number** if the **ID** matches with **21**

```
foreach ($myarray as $array){
  if($array[][id] == "21"){ //this is where I'm making mistake
    $cust_id = $myarray[]['customer_id'];
    return $cust_id;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for finding duplicates guys this also helped a lot in how to search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are **looping** through the **array** you already have a **single item**. So just do it this way

```
foreach ($myarray as $array) {
  if ($array["id"] == "21") {
    return $array["customer_id"];
  }
}
```

Comment: to be picky: `$array['id']` is recommended

Comment: This worked thanks for the answer

Comment: $cust_id = $myarray['customer_id']);!!!! Statement with 2 errors!!! customer_id is not a valid index for $myarray. And unexpected ")"!! How it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom function and call it, like this

```
function arraySearch($theArray, $searchKey, $searchValue, $returnKey){

    foreach($theArray as $value){
            if($value[$searchKey] == $searchValue)  return $value[$returnKey]; //found, return the value of the choosen $returnKey var
    }

     return false; //not found, so return false

}
```

and then use it

```
echo arraySearch($myarray, 'id', '21', 'customer_id'); // it returns 12456
```

[EXAMPLE](http://rextester.com/WSC90182)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($myarray as $array){
  if($array["id"] == 21){
    $cust_id = $array['customer_id'];
    return $cust_id;
  }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low value posts on StackOverflow.  Please improve your answer with how it works and why it is an appropriate solution.